# Add description to security group Ingress array elements in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In Cloudformation, is it possible to add a security group description like the example below?

I see in the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html) but I have never seen 1 official example with a description for the IP rules, only for the `GroupDescription`. I find that very helpful because it helps identifying what that IPs refer to.
So, for example, are these example snippets valid?

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
   "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22",
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
         "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
         "FromPort" : 22,
         "ToPort" : 22,
         "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0",
         "Description" : "some description" <<<<<<<<<here
      } ]
   }
}
```

other example

```
 LoadBalancerSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ['-', [!Ref 'StackName', 'LoadBalancerSG']]
      GroupDescription: Access to the load balancer
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue: 'VpcID'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        Description: 'this IP is ...' <<<<< here
        CidrIp: 10.5.0.0/14
        FromPort: '80'
        ToPort: '80'
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        Description: 'this other IP is ...' <<<<<< here
        CidrIp: 10.5.0.0/14
        FromPort: '8080'
        ToPort: '8080'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SecurityGroupIngress": [{
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "CidrIp": "aa.xx.yy.zz/32",
        "FromPort": "0000",
        "ToPort": "0000"
    }, {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "CidrIp": "bb.xx.yy.zz/32",
        "FromPort": "0000",
        "ToPort": "0000"
    }, {
        "IpProtocol": "tcp",
        "Description": "ELB-EC2",
        "SourceSecurityGroupId": "sg-nnnnnnnnnnnnn",
        "FromPort": "000",
        "ToPort": "000"
    }
],
```

The actual values have been changed for security purposes, but otherwise this is a working template